# iOS get correct CMSampleBuffer orientation for CIDetector

Tags: ios, swift, cidetector

I'm reading in a bunch of videos from a user's camera roll, each as a list of `CMSampleBuffer`s and I want to perform face detection on each frame.

My detection method looks like:

First, I ensure that the buffer is valid. Then I convert the buffer into a `CIImage` and finally, use `CIDetector` to run the face detection.

```
private func facesInBuffer(buffer: CMSampleBuffer) -> [CIFaceFeature] {
    guard let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(buffer) else {
        return []
    }
    let image = CIImage(CVImageBuffer: imageBuffer)
    let detector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeFace, context: nil, options: [CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh, CIDetectorTracking: true])
    guard let features = detector.featuresInImage(image) as? [CIFaceFeature] where !features.isEmpty else {
        return []
    }
    return features
}
```

Since I'm reading these videos in from the camera roll, the orientation can change widely depending on how the video was recorded. And because I want the best detection results, I have to pass in the `CIDetectorImageOrientation`.

I currently have this extension:

```
extension UIImage {
    var coreImageOrientation: CGImagePropertyOrientation {
        switch self.imageOrientation {
        case .Up: return .Up
        case .UpMirrored: return .UpMirrored
        case .Down: return .Down
        case .DownMirrored: return .DownMirrored
        case .Left: return .Left
        case .LeftMirrored: return .LeftMirrored
        case .Right: return .Right
        case .RightMirrored: return .RightMirrored
        }
    }
}
```

but if I convert my buffer into a `UIImage` and pass that images orientation into the detector, no faces are getting detected where there should be faces. And furthermore, when I convert my sample buffer to an image, the orientation, regardless of the video is always the same. Which makes me think the video orientation isn't getting preserved?

How can I get the appropriate orientation value so that face detection works?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?